# Can't get it right (donut icing proportional editing)

Tags: mesh, 3d-view

[image]

[In this video at 33:54](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5Gb1VK98Wc) I m trying to use the tool but instead of the stuff he gets I get this. How do I fix it?

Comment: please add more details of your issue

Comment: Welcome to BSE @TheNoob1 questions or answers based on external video links are not compatible with BSE rules, since links can change, and videos can be removed, please edit your question to be more descriptive without being totally based on video links.

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot to hide the top part of the mesh. What he does is:

- Select the top part and hide it with <kbd>H</kbd>. It leaves a circle.
- Enable the *Proportional Editing* option / *Random* type.
- Select one vertex of the circle.
- Drag the vertex up. As the *Proportional Editing* is enabled, it will randomly affect the other vertices. Increase the effect with the mouse wheel or with the parameters on the bottom of the *Tools* panel (on the left of 3D view, <kbd>T</kbd> to display).
- Unhide the rest of the mesh with <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have proportional editing enabled and on random falloff

[image]

Just  press "O" to disable it and then you can proceed as usual
(you can also use "shift+o" to cycle through different falloff types

Answer (score 0):

Use a **torus** to obtain a donut shape and right after you added it change its radii in the panel to the left.

[image]

The image shows the default settings, but set major radius to 1,5 and minor to 1. Subdivide the torus and apply proportional editing to **faces**. It seems you applied it to vertices and hence it's pointy.